# Unique existence of a weak solution for inhomogeneous parabolic equations in a broader settng than $L^2$? - request for references

Tags: partial-differential-equations, reference-request, cauchy-problem

For notations, let $p \in (1,\infty)$ and $p':=\frac{p}{p-1}$. For $n \in \mathbb{N}$, define $\mathbb{T}^n:= (\mathbb{R} / \mathbb{Z})^n$.

Let us consider the following cauchy problem on $[0,T] \times \mathbb{T}^n$:
\begin{equation}
\partial_t u = \Delta u + f  \text{ with } u(0,x):= u_0(x)
\end{equation}
where $f \in L^{p'}_t H^{-1}_x$ and $u_0 \in L^2(\mathbb{T}^n)$.

We say that $u$ is a weak solution of the above Cauchy problem if
\begin{equation}
u \in L^p_t H^1_x \text{ while } \partial_t u \in L^{p'}_t H^{-1}_x
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
\langle u_t, v \rangle_{H^{-1} \times H^1} + \langle \nabla u, \nabla v \rangle_{L^2} = \langle f, v \rangle_{H^{-1} \times H^1} \text{ for all } v \in H^1(\mathbb{T}^n) \text{ and almost every } t \in [0,T]
\end{equation}
and $u(0)= u_0$.

For $p=p'=2$ and $f \in L^2([0,T] \times \mathbb{T}^n)$, unique existence of a weak solution is presented in detail in Section 7.1 of the textbook "Partial Differential Equations - 2nd Edition" by Evans.

However, I wonder if there is any reference dealing with general $p \in (1,\infty)$ and $f \in L^{p'}_t H^{-1}_x$. Unique existence of a weak solution in this case seems quite plausible to me at least. For example, the notion of Gelfand triple still tells us that $u \in C\bigl([0,T], L^2(\mathbb{T}^n) \bigr)$ so that  the condition $u(0)=u_0$ makes sense.

Could anyone please provide any reference on this topic?